# .htaccess - запретить распространение FilesMatch на вложенные папки

Tags: .htaccess, apache

```
<FilesMatch "^(foo|bar)\.js$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Проблема в том, что будучи расположен в корне, файл влияет на все вложенные папки, делая foo.js и bar.js недоступными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действие директив файла `.htaccess` распространяется на тот каталог, в котором он расположен, а также на все вложенные в него каталоги без ограничения уровня вложенности. Однако, можно переопределить директивы, создав в подкаталоге ещё один файл `.htaccess`. Примерно так:

```
<FilesMatch "^(foo|bar)\.js$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Можно запретить доступ другим способом - при помощи модуля `mod_rewrite`. Следующий код запрещает доступ к файлам, расположенным в корневом каталоге сайта, но разрешает ко всем вложенным:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar)\.js$ - [R=403,L,NC]
```

Comment: А если выполнять запрет на доступ через mod_rewrite, можно как-то ограничить действия текущей директорией?

Comment: @rinart73 Можно. Обновил ответ.